# Css position:fixed code breaks divs positions

Tags: css, positioning

I have a simple HTML page and it contains two `div`s aligned vertically. The page is scrollable because of second `div`. I want the first `div`'s position to be fixed, or nonscrollable, so that only the second `div` is scrollable. I added `position:fixed` to first `div`'s css but this time, the second `div` was placed on first `div`, so the first `div` disappears under the second `div`.

CSS

```
body {
  width:1000px;
  height:100%;
  margin:0 auto;/*body ortalama*/
}

#div1 {
  height:300px;
  background-color:#00CC66;
}

#div2 {
  display:block;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  padding:30px;
  font-size:72px;
  background-color:#FF3;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2">
    <p>
      <!--Content Here-->
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you specify a width for `#div1`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a scroll bar to the second div?

Comment: I think he wants div1 to remain fixed and the rest of the page to scroll as needed.

Comment: Yes I want div1 fixed on page , scrollbar must be used for just div2

Comment: If height of first div is fixed, this can be done with CSS by adding margin-top property for second div (this property must be equal or greater than height of first div). Second solution is to give relative position to second div, with top property. Otherwise, I don't know solution without using jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed is always relative to the parent window, never an element. Once the position is set to fixed its taken out of the document flow.

Fixed positioning is a subcategory of absolute positioning. The only difference is that for a fixed positioned box, the containing block is established by the viewport.

so in the second div2 add these

```
position:relative;
top:300px;    /*Bump it down by the height of div1;*/
```

Hope it helps;

Answer (score 0):

Add this css to `#div2` (you'll need to specify a height for `#div2` otherwise the the scroll bar won't know where to start):

```
  overflow-y:auto;
  height:50px;
```

See the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/38xkn/1/ (scroll to the right first as you've set the `body` width to 100px, then you'll see the scroll bar for `#div2`).

Comment: But I dont know height of div2 because div2 height can change depend on its content.So inner content is dynamic

Comment: You can add `max-height:50px;` instead if you like. That way, if the height exceeds 50px then it'd show the scroll bar. Just change 50px to whatever max-height you want. http://jsfiddle.net/38xkn/2/

Comment: Ok it is better a little bit but I want scrollbar for all page and this scroll bar must scroll just div2.Thanks for effort

Comment: I've created a new answer that should do the job as far as I understand your question and comments above.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a height and set overflow auto instead of scroll because with scroll you will have the scrollbar always even if the content is less than the specified height. For example:

```
#div2 {
    background-color: #FFFF33;
    display: block;
    font-size: 72px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 30px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Hmm but div2 height can change depend on its content.So inner content is dynamic.Can it solve without assigning fix height ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is another option. It's layout is somewhat different but it should get the job done. It uses absolute positioning on div1 to get it to the top, and a percentage width to stop it covering the scroll bar for div2. It's not perfect so you may need to tweek it slightly.

HTML

```
<body>
<div>
     <div id="div1">a</div>
    <div id="div2">
    <p>                               SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSDDDDDDDDDLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDAMSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSDDDDDDDDDLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;/*body ortalama*/
overflow:hidden;
}

#div1{
    height:300px;
    background-color:#00CC66;
position:absolute;
top:0;
width:97.5%;
}

#div2{
    display:block;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    padding:30px;
    font-size:72px;
    background-color:#FF3;
  overflow-y:auto;
  max-height:50px;

    padding-top:300px;
    }
```

EXAMPLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/38xkn/6/